# Regular Expression for multiple zip codes with wild cards

Tags: regex

I have to validate a comma seperated list of zip code such as "95123, 95%, 95222, 95%-8__, 95333"

i have the regular expression ^\d{5}(-?\d{4})?(,\d{5}(-?\d{4})?)*$ that works to get valid zips without underscores and percentage characters. how can i modify the regular expression to work on the example string?

Comment: this one is close. the only thing it doesn't do is allow for % as a zip. ^(((([\d\x5F]{5})|([\d\x5F]{1,4}\x25))(-([\d\x5F]{4})|([\d\x5F]{1,3}\x25))?)\s*,\s*)*(((([\d\x5F]{5})|([\d\x5F]{1,4}\x25))(-([\d\x5F]{4})|([\d\x5F]{1,3}\x25))?)\s*)$

Answer (score 0):

Why not split the string up on commas, then use the regular expression on each zip code?

Comment: great question. it's becuase my validator uses the regex and going around it will be more work than getting a proper regex (i hope)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're not too worried about validation:

```
(?:^|,\s*)([0-9\x25_]{1,5}(?:-[0-9\x25_]{1,4})?)
```

That should do what you need, just perform a match-all to get each entry.

**Note:** I don't do any checks to make sure they have enough numbers (like invalidate **123_** or **%2_-__23** for instance if `_` just means "1 character")

Comment: thanks that's getting close. if the user enters "12345, 12%" the regex should match. if they enter "12345-1" or "95" it should not. in expresso the regex matches invalid zip formats.